# What are those red remote branches on Git?

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm new to git and trying to set up a repository.

I got two branches (`master` and `xyz`).

My workflow so far:

1. change to specific branch, e.g. `git checkout xyz`
2. make changes
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -am 'whatevermessage'`
5. `git push origin xyz`

Everything works so far. But when I `git branch -a` to view all my branches, I get the following output:

```
master
* xyz
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/xyz
```

while `remotes/origin/master` and `remotes/origin/xyz` are displayed in red color. I tried to figure out what the red color means but I couldn't find anything. So, assuming that red is equivalent to some kind of error: **what does the red color mean and how can I fix it?**

Comment: What's in your gitconfig? http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Colors-in-Git

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yellow is local branch while red is a remote branch.

By default:

```
[color "branch"]
    local = yellow
    remote = red
    plain = normal
```

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the red remote branches? What is the point of having a duplicate?

Comment: What on earth is a normal branch?

Comment: Never heard of a normal branch before.